# History server is not receiving any event

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, spark-streaming, pyspark

I am working on streaming application. I tried to configure history server to persist the events of application in Hadoop file system (HDFS). However, it is not logging any events.

I am running Apache Spark 1.4.1 (pyspark) under Ubuntu 14.04 with three nodes.

**Here is my configuration:**

File - `/usr/local/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf`

```
#In all three nodes
spark.eventLog.enabled true 
spark.eventLog.dir hdfs://master-host:port/usr/local/hadoop/spark_log 

#in master node 
export SPARK_HISTORY_OPTS="-Dspark.history.fs.logDirectory=hdfs://host:port/usr/local/hadoop/spark_log"
```

Can someone give list of steps to configure history server?

Comment: How do you start your Spark applications? Do you see any files under `hdfs://master-host:port/usr/local/hadoop/spark_log`?